# "Layer is not valid" error when importing UTM delimited text layer into QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, utm, text

I'm trying to import a small delimited (tab separated) text into QGIS. The coordinates are in UTM format.

[image: printscreen]

**Sample data:**

| id | N | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PT-001 | 7237229 | 146872 |
| PT-002 | 7237230 | 146897 |

The first column contains labels, the other columns (E and N) contain coordinates (numeric integers). I've specified the UTM zone in the Geometric CRS (EPSG:31983), so it seems I don't need it inside the file (there's not even an input field for it).

I'm getting an **error message**:

> Layer is not valid: The layer file:///home/....csv?type=csv&delimiter=%5Ct&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=E&yField=N&crs=EPSG:31983&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason:

The fact that it gives no reason is just a pain. What is possibly happening?

Comment: Add the headers and one line of CSV data as well. You can use fake values, the structure is what is important.

Comment: @user30184 Added it.

Comment: I tried to import your sample data with the same settings and got no issue (QGIS 3.10) ... just copied and pasted (but replaced spaces by tabs)

Comment: @snaileater Strangely, this site is replacing my tabs with spaces, but they're tabs on my original file.

Comment: Works for me with your settings and with the sample data that I copied while in edit mode.

Comment: Do you see sample data in the lowest part of the UI when you are making the settings? Is the file path certainly correct?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, the sample data appears exactly the way it should.

Comment: Could there be some row with different structure, perhaps with fewer fields or having `"`characters in the text while they should only have special meaning as escape characters and delimiters for text fields?

Comment: @user30184 To be sure, I erased all lines, except the two given as a sample above. Same error. Probably something got messed on my system, and I'll have to reinstall QGIS or some of its libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Your Sample Data has mixed spaces and tabs. Stick with one or the other and it'll work.

Comment: No, it only has tabs.

Comment: @Pointdump : how can u say ?

Comment: Rendering the text on the browser is changing some characters. Having a look in edit mode shows that single tab is really used as a separator.